# How can I save my garden?

Tags: lawn, weed-control

My garden has slowly turned into a wild garden with more weeds than grass. The weeds were flowering yellow before I cut last week (I now wish I had taken a photo!). Its small - 7x4 metres.

Is there anyone out there who can advise me how I can turn it back into a grass lawn - it doesn't have to be perfect just no so much of a weed/cabbage patch :)

I have no gardening maintenance but am keen...do I need to dig it all up and re-sow it? Or can I dig up the weeds and put seed down?

[image: garden as it is now]

[image: some close up of the weeds]

Comment: which direction does the garden face? With that moss it looks like north facing.  Are there large trees shading it?

Comment: What part of the world are you in?

Comment: Its south facing but has large trees behind it - I always thought there was a good amount of sun but maybe not. I am in South East, United Kingdom too.

Answer (score 1):

Start with a soil test - that looks like it's "not growing grass because it's not remotely suitable for grass at present" - I'm guessing very acid based on the plant types, but it will probably need more than lime (or wood ashes) as there are likely other issues with soil health here.

Seed is not going to fix this without fixing the soil first.

Depending on "what you really want" there are other short green groundcovers that may be easier to provide for than grass. Duch White Clover is a small/low-growing clover which will help to fix some nitrogen. Thyme or chamomile make "short green plants that smell good and cover the gorund" but are not grass - if your plot is acid and heavily shaded, removing other things and encouraging the moss (or different types of moss, there's quite a variety) may be your best approach.

Presumably some of your yellow flowers were [dandelions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taraxacum), since there is a dandelion seed-head showing in the last picture.

Comment: Keep in mind that once you plant clover it is almost impossible to remove

Comment: thanks for this - it makes perfect sense and I quite like the idea of other green groundcovers. and thanks for the tip on clover. time for me to do some focused research now :)